# Weird spacing for HTML encoded character?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a link that includes a right chevron that has a fairly large font.  The problem that I have run into is that the right chevron has a very large margin above it that creates a big gap between it and the line above.

In addition to this - I would like the text that is next to it to be vertically centered on the point of the chevron.

CSS:

```
.big
{
    font-size:80px;
}
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
This is a test
<div>
    <a href="">Let's Go! <span class="big">&rsaquo;</span></a>
</div>
```

You can see an [example of what I am talking about here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptrxv99n/1/)

Should I just [use a negative margin](http://jsfiddle.net/ptrxv99n/2/) to close up this gap or is there a more graceful way to accomplish what I am trying to do?  How can I center the text on the point of the chevron?  I tried `vertical-align:middle` but had no luck.

Comment: You can use line-height to change the gap. http://jsfiddle.net/ptrxv99n/5/

Comment: A better approach to the original problem of using a symbol for links is to select a character or an image that does require such tuning but can be used within the height of the current font. The chevron characters are designed to be *quotation marks* used in some languages, so they don’t work well as arrows. There is a large number of real array characters in Unicode and even more array icons (images).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `:after` :pseudo-element instead of adding extra element. This way you won't have to position both individually, you could simply position the `a` tag relatively and its `:after` :pseudo-element absolutely. So that the `:after` :pseudo-element will follow wherever you position the `a` tag.

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
a:after {
    content: '›';
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -30px;
}
```

```html
This is a test
<div><a href="#">Let's Go!</a></div>
```

---

Additionally, on Firefox it shows a weird dotted outline, when you click on an `a` element.

[image]

To prevent this, you could set `outline: 0` on `a:focus`.

```css
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
a:after {
    content: '›';
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -30px;
}
a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
This is a test
<div><a href="#">Let's Go!</a></div>
```

Comment: Nice - how is browser compatibility with this?

Comment: @AbeMiessler - It's compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
.big{
    font-size:80px;
    line-height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
    position:relative;
}
</style>

<a href="">Let's Go! <span class="big">&rsaquo;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with relative positioning and line-height definition:

```css
.big {
    font-size:80px;
    line-height: 30px;
    bottom: -10px;
    position: relative;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
This is a test
<div>
    <a href="">Let's Go! <span class="big">&rsaquo;</span></a>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CaseyRule/ptrxv99n/8/

Answer (score 0):

I would use an image and set the background property of your anchor tag to use this image.  You can adjust the padding to however much space you need to accommodate the chevron image.

```
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right:30px;
  background-image: url('/path/to/image.gif');
  background-position: right center;
}
```

This would apply the chevron to all links on your page.  You can of course use a CSS class to limit the chevron to specific hyperlinks.

```
a.chevroned { .... }

<a href="" class="chevroned">Let's Go!</a>
```